FileInfo behaves differently on .NET 2 and .NET 4.8
I have converted a legacy application from .NET 2 to .NET 4.8 and found that the FileInfo API behaves differently on the 2 platforms.
.NET 2:
new FileInfo("C:\a \b").FullName -> "C:\a\b"

.NET 4.8:
new FileInfo("C:\a \b").FullName -> "C:\a \b"

I am wondering if there is any configuration that I can set in app.config/web.config to make .NET 4.8 behave similar to .NET 2.0?
BTW I also find that on both .NET versions, Directory.CreateDirectory will always ignore the spaces at the end such that Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\a    ") will create the folder C:\a.
Could anyone please point me to the corresponding reference of this behavior?

You can get .net2 behavior by specifying the following item in the app.config file:
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IO.UseLegacyPathHandling=true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>

Although Windows does not recommend adding trailing or leading spaces or periods in file names. You can find a warning here.

You should never create a directory or filename with a trailing space. Trailing spaces can make it difficult or impossible to access a directory, and applications commonly fail when attempting to handle directories or files whose names include trailing spaces.


Thanks for the hint. I previously seached with similar results but failed to set it properly in a ASP .NET application. Now I located the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/appcontextswitchoverrides-element Need to set the appSettings instead.  BTW any idea for  Directory.CreateDirectory issue? It seems that this API ignores all tailing spaces...

You need to disable this toggle and use the \\?\ prefix, see this question: https://superuser.com/questions/915197/
